# WCF Endpoint Address not working

Tags: wcf, iis

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong below?  I have been fighting with this for hours and believe that I have it right, but I have to be missing something.  Basically for every service I have I would like to have to addresses.  These services are to be hosted in IIS.  I have been testing with IIS Express.  My expectation is that I would access the services at /AuthService.svc/soap and /AuthService.svc/json, but that doesn't seem to be working.  Below is the config I'm using.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864"/>
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864"/>
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <services>
        <service name="AuthService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceBehavior">
          <endpoint address="soap"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding" 
                  contract="FormsAuthenticatingServices.Interfaces.IAuthService" />
          <endpoint address="json"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
                  contract="FormsAuthenticatingServices.Interfaces.IAuthService" />
        </service>
        <service name="DataService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceBehavior">
          <endpoint address="soap"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
                  contract="FormsAuthenticatingServices.Interfaces.IDataService" />
          <endpoint address="json"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
                  contract="FormsAuthenticatingServices.Interfaces.IDataService" />
        </service>
      </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: when you say "its not working" what failure are you getting? You might want to turn on tracing as well to gain further insight

Comment: I get the service at /authservice.svc but only a blank page at /authservice.svc/soap. Which kind of sucks because that means I don't get my other endpoint. Thanks for the tracing suggestion. I will turn that on, but I'm not sure how much help it will be.

Comment: the config entry u gave there is no base address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the SOAP based metadata at /authservice.svc?wsdl and the REST based operations starting from the URI /authservice.svc/json

You will not see anything in a browser by hitting /authservice.svc/soap as SOAP assumes XML messages will be POSTed to the service whereas the browser is performing a GET. To use the SOAP service create a client project and generate a proxy using Add Service Reference pointing at the WSDL

Comment: Thank you.  I should have known better.  I tried that last night and got an error about address filter mismatch, but instead of troubleshooting that one I thought I screwed something up.  Turns out to fix that issue all I had to do was add [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)] to the services.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Richard's answer, make sure the name attribute on the <service> element is the fully qualified name of the service class.